# Python convert string to array assignment

Tags: python, string, list

In my application I am receiving a string `'abc[0]=123'`

I want to convert this string to an array of items. I have tried `eval()` it didnt work for me. I know the array name `abc` but the number of items will be different in each time.

I can split the string, get array index and do. But I would like to know if there is any direct way to convert this string as an array insert.
I would greately appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: eval should work - but it would be incredibly dangerous to use eval to process external input in this way.  Personally I would split the string (or use a regex).

Comment: `In my application I am receiving a string 'abc[0]=123' `. What sort of application is this, which receives an assignment statement?

Comment: @Abhijit it doesn't matter, which application is generating it? Anyways i will suggest to use `regex`.

Comment: @Netro: It does matter. May be he is solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example with more than one item?

Comment: @Abhijit. it is a web application. I am recieving the arguments like this from an existing application. I am recieving like 'http://url?abc[0]=123&abc[1]=345' I wants to recieve this and store into and array abc.

Comment: @thg435. Please see the above example.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like

```
In [36]: s = "abc[0]=123"

In [37]: vars()[s[:3]] = []

In [38]: vars()[s[:3]].append(eval(s[s.find('=') + 1:]))

In [39]: abc
Out[39]: [123]
```

But this is not a good way to create a variable

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function for parsing urls according to php rules (i.e. using square brackets to create arrays or nested structures):

```
import urlparse, re

def parse_qs_as_php(qs):

    def sint(x):
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            return x

    def nested(rest, base, val):
        curr, rest = base, re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', rest)
        while rest:
            curr = curr.setdefault(
                sint(rest.pop(0) or len(curr)), 
                {} if rest else val)
        return base

    def dtol(d):
        if not hasattr(d, 'items'):
            return d
        if sorted(d) == range(len(d)):
            return [d[x] for x in range(len(d))]
        return {k:dtol(v) for k, v in d.items()}

    r = {}
    for key, val in urlparse.parse_qsl(qs):
        id, rest = re.match(r'^(\w+)(.*)$', key).groups()
        r[id] = nested(rest, r.get(id, {}), val) if rest else val
    return dtol(r)
```

Example:

```
qs = 'one=1&abc[0]=123&abc[1]=345&foo[bar][baz]=555'
print parse_qs_as_php(qs)
# {'abc': ['123', '345'], 'foo': {'bar': {'baz': '555'}}, 'one': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your other application is doing it wrong. It should not be specifying index values in the parameter keys. The correct way to specify multiple values for a single key in a GET is to simply repeat the key:

```
http://my_url?abc=123&abc=456
```

The Python server side should correctly resolve this into a dictionary-like object: you don't say what framework you're running, but for instance Django uses a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) which you can then access using `request.GET.getlist('abc')` which will return `['123', '456']`. Other frameworks will be similar.

Comment: Actually I am working with a facebook application. After send the application request. Facbook is returning the values in this format. So you cant say it is wrong.