# Using regex to find first bracketed content in Python 3

Tags: python, regex

Here's my sample string:

```
[true, {"name": "NameofItem", "amount": "1", "price": 100, "sellerName": "Sellername1", "sellerId": 1},
{"name": "NameofItem2", "amount": "1", "price": 101, "sellerName": "Sellername2", "sellerId": 2}, 22250]
```

I need to find a way of grabbing the first instance of "price" and it's affiliated integer.
I thought I could use re.match and

`(\{.*?\})` to get the first set of content and then convert to a dictionary, but I can't seem to make that work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you just need "price":100 then you can use `\"price\":\d+` - Can you try this ? https://regex101.com/r/02Rqj6/4 and I think re.match finds only the first occurrence of pattern

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a reason why you're not loading this JSON into an in-memory data structure with `json.loads(s)`? Then, you can access properties and traverse it sensibly without regex, e.g. `L[1]["price"]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert string to array assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437064/python-convert-string-to-array-assignment)

Comment: when using re.match it finds "none" but when using re.findall the regex works great and finds all instances of the price. Not sure why re.match doesn't find the first instance.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm still very new to python! Didn't know json.loads was a thing. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex to parse well-formed JSON like this. Use the builtin [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function to parse the JSON string into an in-memory list data structure. Then you can access the first element in the list with `L[1]` and the `"price"` key in that dictionary with `L[1]["price"]`:

```
>>> s = '[true,{"name":"NameofItem","amount":"1","price":100,"sellerName":"Sellername1", "sellerId":1},{"name":"NameofItem2","amount":"1","price":101,"sellerName":"Sellername2","sellerId":2},22250]'
>>> import json
>>> L = json.loads(s)
>>> L
[True, {'name': 'NameofItem', 'amount': '1', 'price': 100, 'sellerName': 'Sellername1', 'sellerId': 1}, {'name': 'NameofItem2', 'amount': '1', 'price': 101, 'sellerName': 'Sellername2', 'sellerId': 2}, 22250]
>>> L[1]["price"]
100
>>> type(L[1]["price"])
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
print(json.loads(input_string)[1]['price'])
```

Comment: @ggorlen- my page was not refereshed when you posted ur answer.